# Default url property is not working when redirecting

Tags: asp.net, .net, url

I'm facing a problem. I have already set the default url in web.config

```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Home.aspx" defaultUrl="Admin/AdminHome.aspx">
            <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
                <user name="admin" password="admin"/>
            </credentials>
        </forms>
    </authentication>
```

but when I try to login using the username, password i think its redirecting to the page itself with the url

```
 /Home.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fAdmin%2fAdminHome.aspx
```

please tell me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

> but when I try to login using the username, password

It seems, that the user with this username/password doesn't have access to the `Admin/AdminHome.aspx` page. That's why you've been redirected to the page defined in `loginUrl` with the `ReturnUrl` parameter.

To make this work, ensure that the logged in user has access right to the `/Admin` folder (or even `Admin/AdminHome.aspx` page).

Comment: the username/password have access to the whole admin folder. Don't know what's the problem behind this.